# Displaying user submitted images

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, windows

i was wondering how websites like ebay allow users to submit items to the website and lay it out so nice. What languages could I learn to do that same type of thing?

So far i've been trying to do it with html/css/java/php and i have not been successful

Comment: Process the images using gd image library, then you can make them more friendly to whatever sizes you want to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to search on these topics my friend:

- Web responsive design and develop
- HTML5, AJAX, CSS3, PHP5 and SQL.
- Using PHP to save data of users and images into the SQL Database and display the info in the site.
- Using Javascript with or without some libraries for Ajax and responsive stuff.
- CSS Stylesheet knowledge on how to make a beautiful looking, attractive site: I recommend CSS-Tricks. Flawless!.
- Alot of time, hard work, effort and a crazy amount of patience.
- Optional things: Coffee, Pen and paper for design and ideas, any graphical design software for layout designing, alot of water to oxygenize your brain and finally: Sleeping well and having often breaks to keep brain-energy ratio positive.

Other addings:

You might want to check out PHP libraries to process images (resizing, crop, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: Any further clearifying on these subjects or more tip requests would be ok. You can comment here and I'll add it to the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Register user, unless you wanna be spammed.
2. Let user upload images, process images to whatever sizes, save images to S3, preferably.
3. Get images
4. Display them.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I was just wondering what S3 is and how can I process images. Sorry if these questions are stupid, i'm sort of new to this.

Comment: S3 is a storage system that does not lie on your server, its a amazon thing. For image manipulation, try https://github.com/thephpleague/glide.
**Note** : when not sure, use google.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for Web responsive
- Use file upload for  image uploading in html

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/  bootstrap link